# Problems with SQL Server Express user instancing and ASP.net Web Application Projects(dotnet nuke)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005-express, dotnetnuke-5

I am trying to connect to SQL Express 2005 through DotnetNuke. My OS is windows 7(IIS 7) and when i tried to connect i got the following error:

> An attempt to attach an auto-named
>   database for file (file
>   location).../Database.mdf failed. A
>   database with the same name exists, or
>   specified file cannot be opened, or it
>   is located on UNC share.

I've tried the solution i found in the following link, but still i get the same error.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2002980

Then I tried to change my SQL Server name from `SYSTEMNAME\SQLEXPRESS` to `SystemIP\SQLEXPRESS` I get a DotNetNuke error as follows:

DotNetNuke Error

> System.ArgumentException: Invalid
>   value for key 'attachdbfilename'. at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString.VerifyLocalHostAndFixup(String&
>   host, Boolean enforceLocalHost,
>   Boolean fixup) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String
>   connectionString) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String
>   connectionString, DbConnectionOptions
>   previous) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(String
>   connectionString,
>   DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions
>   poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions&
>   userConnectionOptions) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(String
>   value) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String
>   value) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String
>   connectionString) at
>   Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(String
>   connectionString, CommandType
>   commandType, String commandText,
>   SqlParameter[] commandParameters) at
>   Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(String
>   connectionString, CommandType
>   commandType, String commandText) at
>   Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(String
>   connectionString, String spName,
>   Object[] parameterValues) at
>   DotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvider.TestDatabaseConnection(DbConnectionStringBuilder
>   builder, String Owner, String
>   Qualifier) at
>   DotNetNuke.Services.Install.InstallWizard.TestDatabaseConnection()
>   at
>   DotNetNuke.Services.Install.InstallWizard.wizInstall_NextButtonClick(Object
>   sender, WizardNavigationEventArgs e)
>   at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Wizard.OnNextButtonClick(WizardNavigationEventArgs
>   e) at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Wizard.OnBubbleEvent(Object
>   source, EventArgs e) at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Wizard.WizardChildTable.OnBubbleEvent(Object
>   source, EventArgs args) at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object
>   source, EventArgs args) at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs
>   e) at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument)
>   at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection
>   postData) at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

can any one help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you show us your connection string being used?? You are **150%** sure that SQL Server 2005 Express is indeed installed on that machine?

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue, found I had to upgrade to `SQLExpress 2008R2` as the sample database was at `2008R2` and i only had `2008 Sp1` installed.

The key was another message, "The database `C:\USERS\....\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF` cannot be opened because it is `version 661`. This server supports `version 655` and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported."

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in IIS7, and it worked:

In `ApplicationPools->DefaultAppPool->Advanced Settings...`, in the `Process Model` section, I set the `Identity` property to `LocalSystem` from the drop-down. The preferred setting for `DotNetNuke` is `NetworkService`.

The `LocalSystem` setting works because the code will connect to the Sql Server using the local identity that was used to log in to the machine. This is required if that login is configured as a login in Sql Server. I reckon if Sql Server logins/identities are modified accordingly, the `NetworkService` setting also should work (I haven't tried this).